# How can I use ng-repeat to display data stored inside a nested object?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongoose

I am working with a document that contains nested data. I've figured out how to store nested data (e.g., comments associated with a post), but I can't figure out how to access that data in a query. Here is what I have:

Node.js

```
app.get('post/:post_id/comments', function(req, res) {
    var Post = require('./models/post');
    Post.find(
        {_id: req.params.post_id},
        null,
        {},
        function (err, data) {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            return res.json(data);
        }
    );
});
```

Mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    post : String,
    comments : [{
        name : String,
        text : String
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', postSchema);
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.getPostComments = function(postID){
    $http({
        url: 'post/'+postID+'/comments',
        method: "GET"
    })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.comments = data.comments;
            console.log(data.comments); // shows "undefined" in the console
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
        });
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in comments">
    {{comment.name}}<br>
    {{comment.text}}
</div>
```

The problem appears to be in `$scope.comments = data.comments;`, but I can figure out how to fix it so the `ng-repeat` will display my comments (instead of just being blank). Any ideas?

Comment: what do you get if you `console.log(data)` instead of `console.log(data.comments)` ?

Comment: ``console.log(data)`` will show "[object Object]", but I'm still now sure how to access the data in the ``ng-repeat`` directive.

Comment: Add `$scope.data = data` to your success function, and `{{data}}` to your view somewhere (outside of the ng-repeat), and tell us what it looks like.

Comment: This is what I get in the console on ``$scope.data = data``: "[{"__v":0,"_id”:”36492070a8hm2a8j7f5fof6s”,”name”:”Joe Blow”,”post”:”This is a post”,”comments”:[{“name”:”Big Bird”,”text”:”This is a comment.”}]]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution was to use the following on the returned data:

```
$scope.comments = data[0].comments;
```